# Python lxml tostring not print nsmap

Tags: python, lxml

I'm working in a Doxygen XML parser. My problem is actually simple, I need to use LXML's `tostring` to get the raw contents of an XML element.

I have it working with ETree, but I switched to LMXL so I get `strip_tags`.

Let's say I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="compound.xsd" version="1.8.16">
  <child2/>
  <child3/>
</root>
```

And I do this:

```
tree = ET.parse('new1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
child3 = root.find("./child3")

objectify.deannotate(child3, cleanup_namespaces=True, xsi=True, pytype=True)
etree.cleanup_namespaces(child3)
child3.nsmap.clear()
etree.strip_attributes(child3, 'nsmap') 

print(ET.tostring(child3, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

This is what I get:

```
<child3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

This is what I WANT:

```
<child3/>
```

Is there an option to tostring to *NOT* print nsmap?

I tried:

If I try

```
root.nsmap = None
```

I get an exception:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'nsmap' of 'lxml.etree._Element' objects is not writable
```

I'm using Python 3.7 64 bits with Windows 10.

Thank you.

Comment: Changing `root = etree.Element("root", nsmap=nsmap)` to `root = etree.Element("root")` seems like the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Well, perhaps that like is part of the Minimum Working Example and t is not part of my actual code. At the bottom part of my question, I explain where the real XML comes from. When the real XML gets parsed, I get the 'nsmap' property set. So my question is: *given an Element object with 'nsmap' property set, how do I make `tostring` *NOT* print it.

Comment: The root element in your demo document has a `xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` declaration, but the namespace is not actually used. So the declaration will be removed by calling `etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)`.  https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#cleanup_namespaces

Comment: Yes, that is true, but not in my actual code as I explicitly said in my question. So your solution is to fix my example? Any suggestions on how to address the problem at hand?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the example does not properly demonstrate your real problem, then yes, you should "fix" the example (provide a [mcve]). Btw, the part of the question that you call the "full context" was not helpful at all when I tried to understand what the problem is. Seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: I just updated my example to use an XML file, as you can see, the namespace is ALWAYS printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the XML document, the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace is in use. The `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute is bound to that namespace.

In order to get the wanted output, you must 1) remove the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute and 2) remove the declaration of the namespace.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('new1.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Remove the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute
del root.attrib["{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation"]

# Remove the declaration for the now unused namespace. Must be done on the root element
etree.cleanup_namespaces(root)

child3 = root.find("./child3")

# Print child3
print(etree.tostring(child3, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))

# Print the whole document
print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<child3/>


<root version="1.8.16">
  <child2/>
  <child3/>
</root>
```